# Kotlin. Merge two list with alternating values

Tags: arrays, kotlin, array-merge, alternating

Is there a ready-made solution for creating an list by alternating elements from two list. I understand how this can be done using loops and conditions, but perhaps there is a ready-made extension that will allow you to solve the problem concisely

Answer (score 3):

You can use zip and flatMap result.

```
    val list1 = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    val list2 = listOf(4, 5, 6)
    val result = list1.zip(list2).flatMap { pair -> listOf(pair.first, pair.second) }
```

note that this solution executes extra memory allocation for each pair so my recommendation is still to implement your own version.

```
fun <T> List<T>.mix(other: List<T>): List<T> {
    val first = iterator()
    val second = other.iterator()
    val list = ArrayList<T>(minOf(this.size, other.size))
    while (first.hasNext() && second.hasNext()) {
        list.add(first.next())
        list.add(second.next())
    }
    return list
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if the arrays are of different lengths, then one element will not be added to the result array.

Comment: The question only asks for a library function for "alternating elements" and does not specify what to do when there are extra elements. This answer answers the question asked, IMO.